# Issues parsing some JSON Data - Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, codable

I think this will be simple I assume I'm just missing something about JSON structure here. I have some code that pulls down some data from an API handle to get a list of country names:

https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name

Here is a sample of the API data though please feel free to view it using the link above:

```
[{"name":"Afghanistan"},{"name":"Åland Islands"},{"name":"Albania"},{"name":"Algeria"},{"name":"American Samoa"},{"name":"Andorra"},{"name":"Angola"},{"name":"Anguilla"},{"name":"Antarctica"},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda"},{"name":"Argentina"}
```

I created this struct to hold the data

```
struct CountryList: Codable {
    public let country: [Country]
}

struct Country: Codable {
    public let name: String
}
```

I have these two functions that create the URLRequest and then grab the data and return it via a completion handler:

```
private func setupApiUrlRequest(apiURL: String) throws -> URLRequest {
    let urlString = apiURL
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        print("Error setting up URL")
        throw CountriesError.invalidURLString
    }

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    return request
}

func getCountries(completion: @escaping (Country?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) {
    if let request = try? setupApiUrlRequest(apiURL: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name") {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data,response,error in
            guard let data = data else {
                completion(nil, response, error)
                return
            }
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let downloadedCountries = try decoder.decode(Country.self, from: data)

                completion(downloadedCountries, response, nil)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(nil, response, error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

This gives me an error:

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

So it seems like my Struct is not correct somehow but I am just not sure how. Can anyone offer any guidance? I have a few other functions using almost identical code that grab API JSON Data and decode it into structs... just missing something here.

Comment: **Never ever** `print(error.localizedDescription)`. Print the `error` instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JSON` you've provided is not in the correct format.

**Valid JSON:**

```
[{"name":"Afghanistan"},{"name":"Åland Islands"},{"name":"Albania"},{"name":"Algeria"},{"name":"American Samoa"},{"name":"Andorra"},{"name":"Angola"},{"name":"Anguilla"},{"name":"Antarctica"},{"name":"Antigua and Barbuda"},{"name":"Argentina"}]
```

You need to use the `[Country].self` instead of just `Country.self` while `parsing`, i.e.

```
do {
    let downloadedCountries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data)
    print(downloadedCountries)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Also, there is not requirement of `struct CountryList`. You can remove that.

Comment: Sorry I copied the JSON snippet quickly as I was heading to lunch and forgot to add the closing ]. Using an array of Country, [Country].self works. How come I could not use the additional struct countryList which had one variable [Country]?

Comment: @EdwardS. A struct represents always a dictionary. There is no dictionary with key `country`. The root object is an array.